# How to setup a User Model that can be used for a user that is an employee and a user that is a client?

Tags: oop, ruby-on-rails-4

```
Rails 4.2
Devise for Login
Pundit or CanCan for Authorization
Rolify for roles
```

I am working on a application that will have both employees and clients:

```
Employees - can have 1 or more roles: Proofreader, Admin, Super Admin, Manager -  have an employee_profile

Clients - can purchase proofreading_jobs - have a client_profile

Employees that have role *proofreader* can have proofreading_jobs.


The client_profile contains different data from the employee_profile.
```

I would like to design this application using best OO practices and make it scalable and flexible, however I have limited experience.

Should I make separate models for Employee and Client or should I make one User model?

If the answer is one User model how would I distinguish between an Employee and a Client in the app?

Comment: Isn't that "User" is a person with, let's say an e-mail as unique identifier? Then a "User" can be "Client" or "Employee" or even both. My thinking would be to have "User" model where everything related to "Users" is done. Then in another model you can have some information related to "User" - if it has some role or whatever other data you need to tie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, unfortunately, is one of those question with no definitive answer and no matter how much experience you have with OOP, chances are you will get something wrong anyways. However, there are some good concepts and starting points to use when modeling stuff like this.

Personally, I think [Avdi Grimm has it right in this post](https://www.rubytapas.com/2015/10/01/episode-346-user-model/) and I try to avoid using the generic "User" model in most cases.
You could have a UserAccount or Account model to represent the authentication specific data (username, password) and an account has a profile (client or employee in your case) and roles (Proofreader, Admin, Super Admin...).

So, now your question is not answered at all: Should you use distinguished models for employee and client profiles?
It really depends on how much they share, if they are pretty much the same and only distinguished by their name, you should consider using [single table inheritance](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/), if they only share a few attributes, then you could go for a basic Profile model with generic attributes - you do not want to have a "Attribute" model though, that would clash with active records `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#attributes`, so you would have to name it ProfileAttribute or something like that.

The problem however might be that the gems you use follow a different approach and it would be very hard to make them work with what I am thinking of, so you would need a more pragmatic approach. Anyways, this is one of the possible approaches:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Barebone account model:
  # id
  # username
  # password_hash

  has_many :roles
  has_one :profile # or has_many :profiles
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Whatever attributes you want to have in both, client and employee profile,
  # for example:
  # id
  # public_name

  has_many :profile_attributes
  belongs_to :account
end

class ProfileAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This is pretty much as generic as it gets
  # id
  # name
  # value
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

This is just a basic idea, since no one knows enough about your project and like I said, there is no 1 size fits all answer. Hope this helps anyways.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I guess I was hoping that since there must be a lot of applications out there that have both Employees and Clients that there might be some standards on best ways to organize the code.

Comment: After watching the video from Avdi Grimm I think I will try to implement the code above as it eliminates the need to have Employee or Client models. Just account models.  I will give it a try and see how the gems I'm using deal with this setup.

Comment: Ninigi wouldn't ProfileAttribute be a belongs_to_many :profiles as each profileattribute could belong to each Profile so that an Account with a Client role  would have a profile with one set of profile attributes while an account with a proofreader role would have another profile with different profile attributes.

Comment: @chell Well, I guess you could have the attributes have many profiles, it really depends on what your goals are. If an attribute belongs to many profiles, that would mean that if you edit that attribute, it will change for all profiles - in some cases that might exactly be what you want, but I guess in most cases that would be an unwanted behaviour.